# blupy read value from chacteristics as integer and not as ascii

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, decoding

I use the `bluepy` module to connect to an Arduino board with BLE running a [battery monitor](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/blob/master/examples/Peripheral/BatteryMonitor/BatteryMonitor.ino).

My Python script is working perfectly fine. I get the values I expect. But I do not like the solution because the binary value read from the characteristic is interpreted as an ASCII character before getting the decimal representation of that ASCII character.

I tried to use the binascii module

```py
val = binascii.b2a_hex(ch.read())
val = binascii.unhexlify(val)
val = struct.unpack('f', val)[0]
```

But this only works with even string lengths. And I had other problems with it I can't remember right now.

My current soluion with "double casting" is here.

```py
from bluepy.btle import Peripheral, BTLEException, UUID
import sys
import time
try:
    print("Trying to Connect to Device")
    p = Peripheral() # 3rd param = 0 means /dev/hci0, 1 means /dev/hci1
    p.connect("7C:9E:BD:3A:D0:A2")
    uuid = UUID(0x180F)
except BTLEException as e:
    sys.exit(e)
else:
    print("Connection established")
finally:
char = p.getServiceByUUID(uuid).getCharacteristics()[0]
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        # TODO react to the notification instead of looping
        val = char.read()
        # Yes this works but is definitly not the way to do it right
        # reading the characteristics interpreted it as ascii and than
        # converting this ascii too it coresponding integer value
        print(ord(val.decode()))
        time.sleep(0.2)
        i+=1
    p.disconnect()
```

But I really dislike the 4th last line. While it gets me the expected values, I feel like it's just bad code.

```py
print(ord(val.decode()))
```

It looks like in this case python automatically assumes that the value should be interpreted as ASCII as it prints the corresponding ASCII value, even if I do not decode it. For example, I get `b'/'` printed out when I do not decode it, and just `/` when I decode it, so the battery level is 47% which is correct.

Directly casting `val`  from base 2 representation to an integer does not work:

```py
print(int(val,2))
```

Python assumes that `val` is to be read as an ASCII character so the casting fails.

**TLDR:** I'm looking for a solution which replaces

```py
print(ord(val.decode()))
```

With something more fancy where I don't cast the binary value read from the characteristics to an ASCII character and then get the corresponding decimal value for the character.

Just something which reads the binary value as decimal immediately. It also can be another module.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic read is returning bytes e.g `b'/'`. If you want to convert that into an integer then the `int.from_bytes()` functionality is useful. e.g:

```py
>>> val = b'/'
>>> batt = int.from_bytes(val, byteorder='little', signed=True)
>>> print(f'Battery level is: {batt}%')
```

which gives the output:
`Battery level is: 47%`

The `/` being printed is just an artifact of Python trying to be helpful when you print bytes. If you wrap the bytes in a list you will see the true value. e.g:

```py
>>> print(b'\x2f\x2a\x26\x20')
b'/*& '
>>> list(b'/*& ')
[47, 42, 38, 32]
>>> [f'{_:2x}' for _ in b'/*& ']
['2f', '2a', '26', '20']
```

In your question you attempted to use the `struct` module in Python. The conversion can be done with that also:

```py
>>> batt = struct.unpack('<b', b'/')[0]
>>> print(batt)
47
```

The little endian byte order is not strictly necessary for a single byte value but it is good practice when working with Bluetooth as the data is normally in little endian format.